# jquery-2.1.1 .sortable()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got this code and need to make it sortable with jquery-2.1.1 (connected lists)

`class="sensorContainer"` has to be sortable in all  divs from `class="groupContainerBody"` handling by `img class="img_control_move"` and `class="groupContainer"`  has to be sortable in  `div class="outerContainer"` `img class="img_control_move"`.

```
<div class="outerContainer">
       <div class="groupContainer ui-state-default">
                <div class="groupContainerHead">
                    <div id="ungrouped" class="groupName"> 
                        <input id="ungrouped" class="chartNameInput" type="text" autocomplete="on" value="ungrouped" title="ungrouped">                                           
                    </div>
                    <div class="groupContainerMove">
                        <img class="img_control_move" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/control_move.png" width="16" height="16">
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="groupContainerDel">
                        <img class="img_control_del" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/control_del.png" width="16" height="16">
                    </div>    
                </div>    
                <div id="groupContainerBody1" class="groupContainerBody">
                       <div id="sensor_28ff588762140363" class="sensorContainer ui-state-default"> 
                            <div class="sensorName">
                                <input id="sensor_28ff588762140363" class="sensorNameInput" type="text" autocomplete="on" value="sensor_28ff588762140363" title="sensor_28ff588762140363">
                            </div>               
                            <div class="sensorMove">
                                <img class="img_control_move" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/control_move.png" width="16" height="16">
                            </div>                  
                        </div><!-- sensorContainer -->
                        <div id="sensor_28ffd55562140342" class="sensorContainer ui-state-default"> 
                            <div class="sensorName">
                                <input id="sensor_28ffd55562140342" class="sensorNameInput" type="text" autocomplete="on" value="sensor_28ffd55562140342" title="sensor_28ffd55562140342">
                            </div>               
                            <div class="sensorMove">
                                <img class="img_control_move" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/control_move.png" width="16" height="16">
                            </div>                  
                        </div><!-- sensorContainer -->
                        <div id="sensor_28ffed57621403ff" class="sensorContainer ui-state-default"> 
                            <div class="sensorName">
                                <input id="sensor_28ffed57621403ff" class="sensorNameInput" type="text" autocomplete="on" value="sensor_28ffed57621403ff" title="sensor_28ffed57621403ff">
                            </div>               
                            <div class="sensorMove">
                                <img class="img_control_move" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/control_move.png" width="16" height="16">
                            </div>                  
                        </div><!-- sensorContainer -->
                </div><!-- groupContainerBody -->
            </div><!-- groupContainer -->     
    </div>
```

Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: Can't you post a working fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dobri/zdmwgaf4/

Comment: It is now workin - http://jsfiddle.net/Dobri/zdmwgaf4/3/